# "Как бы" и "типа"

Tags: пунктуация

Современная, особенно молодежная, речь часто усеяна оборотами вроде "как бы" и "типа". Являются ли они вводными и выделяются ли запятыми на письме?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Частицы *как бы* и *типа* не являются вводными словами и не обособляются на письме.