# Запятая после «как бы»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Как бы, добро пожаловать.

На сайтах пишут, что запятая после «как бы» не нужна, но можно ли поставить ее, чтобы изобразить паузу?

Comment: Повтор вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0?s=2|47.6354

Comment: А какое предложение было перед этим? Может быть, это был вопрос, на который можно ответить словами "как бы"? _- Вы тут гостей принимаете? - Как бы, добро пожаловать._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Как бы добро пожаловать!**

Об уместности выражения можно говорить с учетом контекста и конкретной ситуации.

***КАК БЫ*** является здесь **частицей**, пауза в таких случая не делается и запятая не ставится.

Частица ***как бы*** не так давно появилась в нашем языке сначала **в обыденной речи, но потом стала активно употребляться и в других ситуациях.** У нее есть определенное значение – **выражение неопределенности и сомнения**, поэтому пользоваться ею надо грамотно, а не превращать в бессмысленное междусловное междометие, что говорит о некачественной речи и просто плохом вкусе.

**О частице *КАК БЫ***

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_148

В современном русском литературном языке ***как бы*** выступает в качестве:

у**подобляющей частицы**, выражает приблизительное сходство, подобие (Отвечает как бы нехотя);

**союза**: выражает сравнение (Зашуршало в траве, как бы прополз кто-то).

Comment: А на мой взгляд, присказка-наполнитель "как бы" практически отжила свое (пик приходился на середину 90-х) и сменилась на "типа" или варварски используемое "в том числе" (последние лет 7).

Comment: Это у вас в Питере, а у нас еще говорят.  Например: я как бы не знаю.  Или: как бы да, может быть и т.д. Или (в конце высказывания на какую-либо тему): как бы так. Культурные люди, конечно,  против, считают, что это слово-паразит. Вот интересная запись речи будущего депутата: "Я вам авторитетно заявляю, что став как бы депутатом, сделаю так, что бы вы... . как бы ни в чем не нуждались. И вы как бы в любое время шли ко мне в кабинет".  http://www.proza.ru/2012/07/11/700

Comment: Ну, написав "чтобы" из его речи раздельно, приписали дополнительную неграмотность якобы ему.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то странное есть в этом предложении. Трудно судить в отрыве от контекста, но я бы лучше воспринял такую фразу с кавычками:  **Как бы "добро пожаловать"**. Или даже так: **Как бы "Добро пожаловать!"**.

Например такой отрывок:

> Встречающие... надели нам белые шарфики. Подумалось: «Это как бы "Добро пожаловать в королевство счастья!"»

В любом случае не вижу ни паузы, ни других причин для постановки запятой.